# Access storyboard progress bar in another view

Tags: ios

I have a storyboard view controller with some labels and a progress bar.

In my view, I load the storyboard view with:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
GeodatebaseLoadingViewController *geodatabaseLoading = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GeodatabaseLoading"];
[self.view addSubview:geodatabaseLoading.view];
```

Edit:
I linked the progress bar to the GeodatabaseLoading class, and access it with `geodatabaseLoading.progressBar`

Am I doing this right?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please include more of your code so that we can see where exactly the code you included reside? Are you trying to update the value of the progressbar in the view of the "loading" viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new class which inherits UIViewController. Lets call it `NorCalKnockOutViewController` In interface builder go to the class inspector and set the class of your loading controller to this new class.

Change you code to:

```
NorCalKnockOutViewController *loading = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Loading"];
```

CTRL drag the progress bar into the header for your class to create an IBOutlet for the progress bar. Call it `progressBar`.

You can now access it in your code using:

```
UIProgressBar *pBar=loading.progressBar;
```

Comment: This won't work until the view of the loading viewcontroller pushed on the screen

Comment: So `[self.view addSubview:loading.view]` ?

Comment: That would be a poor solution because some lifecycle methods will no longer be called on the loading viewcontroller. I don't get what exactly you are trying to do here so can'T give a proper advice about what to do. Please be more clear in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the progressbar in the viewcontroller instance you have just created because its view won't be loaded until you display it on the screen. This means that there is no progress for you to access at that point.

If you want to update the progressbar in `geodatabaseLoading`, then you should define an ivar inside `GeodatebaseLoadingViewController` and set its value whenever you need. Then in `GeodatebaseLoadingViewController`s `viewWillAppear` method, you can set the value of the actual progressbar (which is now guaranteed to exist) using the ivar you had created.

Your code, in its current state would work but it is a poor practice that needs to be changed. You can't randomly add a view to the screen just so you can access an outlet connected to one of its subviews.

Comment: I want to change the progress bar values

Comment: I want to load a view onto another view, that has a progress bar and update the progress bar with values.